# Adding if statement to a Netsuite Script

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I am wanting to display lot numbers on item fulfilment and invoices.
I don't have any scripting ability... sadly...

So I implemented this script and it works really well.
https://jcurvesolutions1.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4711971574425-Remove-Bin-Number-from-item-inventorydetail-When-Printing-with-Advanced-PDF-Templates

```js
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'],
function(record) {

    function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
        var rec = scriptContext.newRecord;
        var lines = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:'item'});
        var tempS = '';

        for(var i=0;i<lines;i++){ // for each line

            var subList = rec.getSublistSubrecord({
                    sublistId:'item',
                    fieldId:'inventorydetail',
                    line:i
                });

            if(subList.getValue('id')){ //if the line has inventory details
                var sublistLines = subList.getLineCount({
                        sublistId:'inventoryassignment'
                    });
                for(var j=0;j<sublistLines;j++){ //for each line of the inventory details
                    tempS+=subList.getSublistText({
                        sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
                        fieldId:'issueinventorynumber',
                        line:j
                    });
                    if(j<sublistLines-1) tempS+='\n';
                }
                rec.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId:'item',
                    fieldId:'custcol_tb_lot_no_via_js',
                    line:i,value:tempS
                });
                tempS='';
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    };
});
```

However I have one issues with it.
In our Netsuite account I have it set up so that Invoices display items that are on Backorder.
However backorder items don't have "inventory detail" so when I try and edit or save the invoice I get the following error.

```js
{"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"USER_ERROR","message":"Invalid number (must be positive)","stack":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","beforeSubmit(/SuiteScripts/DisplayLot# Packing Slip.js:16)"],"cause":{"type":"internal error","code":"USER_ERROR","details":"Invalid number (must be positive)","userEvent":"beforesubmit","stackTrace":["anonymous(N/serverRecordService)","beforeSubmit(/SuiteScripts/DisplayLot# Packing Slip.js:16)"],"notifyOff":false},"id":"","notifyOff":false,"userFacing":false}
```

It is due to one of the lines not having any inventory detail as it is on back order.
so what I am asking is if some kind person could tell me what I need to change in the above script so that it ignores backorder items.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To ignore backordered line items, you must get the back ordered quantity per line item.  In my UI I see the field id "backordered", however in the [NS records browser](https://www.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/srbrowser/Browser2021_1/script/record/invoice.html) the field id is "quantityremaining".  See which works for you.

```
var backOrderedQty = rec.getSublistValue({sublistId: 'item', fieldId: 'backordered', line: i}); //or try field id quantityremaining
```

then evaluate if it is equal to 0.  If it is, then do not proceed with code for this line. If it is, then do proceed. Example:

```
if(backOrderedQty == 0) {
  //do nothing
} else {
  //do something
}
```

In your code, you already have a check for if the line has inventory details.  So we can add this check for back ordered quantity to the same if statement and we do not need an else statement, since we want to "do nothing".

Full code, with modified lines not indented:

```
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.x
 * @NScriptType UserEventScript
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */
define(['N/record'],
function(record) {

    function beforeSubmit(scriptContext) {
        var rec = scriptContext.newRecord;
        var lines = rec.getLineCount({sublistId:'item'});
        var tempS = '';

        for(var i=0;i<lines;i++){ // for each line

//get the current lines backordered qty
var backOrderedQty = rec.getSublistValue({
   sublistId: 'item',
   fieldId: 'backordered', //or quantityremaining
   line: i
});
            
            var subList = rec.getSublistSubrecord({
                    sublistId:'item',
                    fieldId:'inventorydetail',
                    line:i
                });

if(subList.getValue('id') && backOrderedQty ==0){ //if the line has inventory details AND back ordered qty is 0
                var sublistLines = subList.getLineCount({
                        sublistId:'inventoryassignment'
                    });
                for(var j=0;j<sublistLines;j++){ //for each line of the inventory details
                    tempS+=subList.getSublistText({
                        sublistId:'inventoryassignment',
                        fieldId:'issueinventorynumber',
                        line:j
                    });
                    if(j<sublistLines-1) tempS+='\n';
                }
                rec.setSublistValue({
                    sublistId:'item',
                    fieldId:'custcol_tb_lot_no_via_js',
                    line:i,value:tempS
                });
                tempS='';
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit
    };
});
```

Comment: A nice trick to seeing the field ids for your specific account is to use a 3rd party tool like the NetSuite record JSON viewer chrome extension.  Another option is to add "&xml=T" to any exiting NS url then enter to see the xml version of the page.  Ctrl +F for "machine name="item"" to see the line item details.  From there you should be able to find a good field id to use to distinguish the back ordered lines from the not back ordered lines.

Comment: Great Advice, Let me give that a try.

I did a bit more digging and there might be something else at play here. I was looking at an Invoice that was giving me the error and even though it was on back order it was still wanting inventory detail for some reason. so when it went to save, the script would run and give the error saying it has to be a positive. 

But then I tested it on another Invoice that had an item on Backorder and it didn't error out. mmmmm

I will keep digging, but again thank you for taking the time to help, that pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: Good luck!  Sometimes adding frequent logs can be helpful to identify which line or value is causing the issue.  Also when NS throws errors, like from the one you provided "/SuiteScripts/DisplayLot# Packing Slip.js:16" means check that script on line 16. Line 16 is likely the culprit.

Comment: So I tried your script - Thank you. I am not sure why but now it doesn't work at all. I don't get any errors but it is now not populating the lot numbers.

I have been trying to look at the logs for the script but it doesn't show what fulfilment or Invoice is causing it to fail and trying to fine the right one is like a needle in a hay stack.
Is there a way to capture what what record it is failing on. At least that way I can start to narrow down the problem.